# DDMS has blank screen

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

when I last used the DDMS from Android Studio I tried open *.hprof file, but the whole screen changed to blank. 
[image: The blank screen of DDMS]

Now the screen is always blank. I reinstall Android Studio, Eclipse and of course SDK, but with no effect.

Can you someone tell me how to reapir it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, and I arrived at it the same way (trying to open a heap dump *.hprof file). Resetting the perspective does not work.

How I fixed it:

1. go into **.android** folder in your home directory
2. there should be a **monitor-workspace** folder; move it to a backup directory (or delete it)
3. restart **DDMS**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reset the perspective with a right-click on the DDMS button.

Comment: I of course tried it, but with no effect. Do you have any next idea? Thanks

Comment: Shortcut to open a View. `Alt+Shift+Q, Q` on Windows

Comment: It does not respond to any action. I can click to show view, but there is no shown.